# Array as array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'd like to have multiple values output the same object in a key array.

```
"myobject": {
  ["foo", "bar"]: "foobar"
}
```

Is there a way in javascript to use an array as a key in a key array, so if I were to input either `"foo"` or `"bar"`, it would give me `"foobar"`?

Answer (score 0):

No, [json.org](http://json.org/), the key must a string

Answer (score -2):

You could make it a string which just happens to be an array when passed through `eval()`, but it's probably not an ideal data structure.